# Delphi grid with a different data type in each row, displayed dynamically

Tags: delphi, tdbgrid

I am trying to create a Delphi grid to allow display and edit in a db grid of data that might have a different data type on each row. I would like to display a specific control for each data type, e.g. when the data type is DateTime, I want to display my custom edit control that allows typing a date in or popping up a calendar.

The data looks something like this:

```
Name   DataType   DateValue   StringValue   BooleanValue     
---------------------------------------------------------
A      Date       1/1/2007 
B      String                 asdf
C      Boolean                              True
```

...and in the db, this table has a column for each possible type of value. So, there is a `BooleanValue` column, `DateValue`, etc.

What I would like to do is display a single 'Value' column in the grid that displays the appropriate edit control depending on what the 'DataType' is for that row. So, the grid should look like :

```
Name   DataType   Value     
---------------------------
A      Date       1/1/2007 
B      String     asdf
C      Boolean    True
```

It seems I will need to display a different edit control (to allow the user to edit the `Value` column) for each row dynamically based on the value of the `DataType` column. I know there are more advanced grids out there that handle this sort of problem, but the powers that be will not allow anything but what is available out-of-the-box with Delphi.

Any ideas on how to make something like this work?

Comment: It sounds like you're going to be overloading your grid's "OnDraw" event

Comment: Trying to find an out of the box solution or a 3rd party control for this is pointless. What you're telling does not fit into a data table concept.

Comment: What type are the fields in the database? String?

Comment: In the database, DateValue is a DateTime, StringValue is a String, BooleanValue is a BIT, etc.

Comment: greatis has a set of inspector components, including a TDBInspector. It may do what you need but isn't free: http://www.greatis.com/delphicb/objinsp/

Comment: The Powers That Be should go ahead and implement it themselves then.  This is Delphi, and in Delphi, you write your own controls, and you use controls other people wrote. Anybody who says you shouldn't is a moron. I could write a perfectly workable implementation of your question in a custom control using my "virtual grid" control in about 2 hours. But I won't bother even posting an answer unless the "no external controls" requirement goes away, because that's just dumb.

Answer (score 4):

Personally, I would not go for editing directly inside the `TDBGrid` in this case, since your Table is not DB normalized (I don't use it in any case actually). I would have used a Calculated field to *display* the desired value in the grid, And dynamically created the `TDBxxxEdit`s on the form for each field type (How about your own `TDBTreeEdit` for example, a `TDBRichEdit`, or a DB Image pickup editor, etc...?).

In case you do want to use your own controls on the `TDBGrid`, and replace the default `TInplaceEdit` editor, you can refer the following article: [Adding components to a DBGrid](http://delphi.about.com/od/usedbvcl/l/aa081903a.htm), and a related article: [Displaying and editing MEMO fiels in Delphi's TDBGrid](http://delphi.about.com/library/weekly/aa030105a.htm)

Answer (score 3):

Displaying all of the data in the same column is quite easy. You can simply add a calculated string field, and change the value according to what you are storing in that row.

The editing is quite a bit more complicated. If you want to have an in-place editor, you are in for a world of hurt... I've done it, it's a pain, and takes a lot of time. If you want to display a dialog to edit the value, that's much easier. You can add a column objects to the grid and you can setup the column you have attached to the calc field to display a button. When the button is clicked you simply display the editing dialog needed for that row, and commit the edits when the dialog is closed.

There are other ways to get this done, but I would say the above would be the shortest way. Other ways may include custom draw events to display your data in one column, intercept clicks to create your own editor, etc, etc, etc...

Answer (score 0):

after add calculated fields . 
Sample:

```
procedure OnCalculate(DataSet:TDataSet);
begin
  case IndexText(DataSet['ValueType'],['Date','String','Boolean']) of 

    0:DataSet['DateValue']:=StrToDateTime(DataSet['Value']); // also converting
    1:DataSet['StringValue']:=DataSet['Value'];
    2:DataSet['BooleanValue']:= MatchText(DataSet['Value'],['1','True','T','Y','Yes']);
{etc datatypes}
   end;
end;
```